# Foreach over Excel cells only returns the first row in run, but works properly when stepping through the method

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I'm using an Excel spreadsheet as a data table for time period history.  The structure is this:

```
ID  Person      Start   End
1   Alan        5/1     5/3
2   Bobbi       5/3     5/4
3   Chuck       5/1     5/2
5   Eugenia     5/3     5/6
6   Chuck       5/10    5/12
```

`Start` and `End` are formatted as Date fields.

I wrote a method in a VBA module to query this table and return all rows for a given person, such as `Chuck`.  In SQL, this is easy enough (`select fields from History where Person = something`).  I am currently using a `foreach` loop and testing the value of `Person`.  My loop reads as follows:

```
Public Sub UpdatePeriod(currentPeriod as timePeriod)

Dim indexCell As Range
Dim colPeriods As New Collection
Dim priorPeriod As timePeriod

For Each indexCell in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History").Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
    If Not (indexCell Is Nothing) And IsNumeric(indexCell) = True Then
        Set priorPeriod = GetPeriodObject(indexCell)
        If (priorPeriod.Person = currentPeriod.Person) Then
            colPeriods.Add priorPeriod
        End If
    End If
Next

'Do stuff with the entries in colPeriods....
End Sub
```

I have set up the spreadsheet so that a certain sheet's `Worksheet_Change` event handler will pass a `timePeriod` object to this method.  So far, everything works properly (though there's probably a better way).

When I test the method without breaking before the `For Each`, the loop only goes over row 2 (as row 1 contains the headers).  But when I do break before the loop, the loop properly goes over all rows.

How do I improve this method to return all rows of interest?

(Note: The project is using VBA as a prototype, and eventually will be a proper application with a proper database.  I aim to make the data interface look exactly the same as the application implementation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you haven't qualified the second `Range` call (or `Rows`). Use:

```
For Each indexCell in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History").Range("A2:A" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History").Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
```

Using a variable for the worksheet would simplify things!

Comment: OK, I'll drop a `With` into this part and give your code a try.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. Thanks very much.  (Silly single character error.)

Answer (score 0):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("History")
    For Each indexCell in .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        ....
    Next
End With
```